# How to plot $W(\exp(-x))$ in wolframalpha or sage

Tags: graphing-functions, lambert-w

[image]

I tried to plot the function $W(\exp(-x))$ in both WolframAlpha and Sage and I got:

1. No result in Wolframalpha (empty 3d box or 2d chart).
2. Empty set in SAGE.

Any help?

Comment: Try `ComplexPlot[ LambertW[Exp[-z]], {z, -6-6I, 6+6I}]` in Mathematica.

Comment: The same code, with `Plot` instead, gives [abs/arg plots](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Plot%5B+LambertW%5BExp%5B-z%5D%5D%2C+%7Bz%2C+-6-6I%2C+6%2B6I%7D%5D) in Wolfram Alpha. You can also type $z=x+y i$ and get [im/re plots](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Plot%5BLambertW%28exp%28%28x%2By+i%29%29%29%2C%7Bx%2C-6%2C6%7D%2C%7By%2C-6%2C6%7D%5D)

Comment: And with SAGE as program -I have no Mathematica license?

Comment: You can try any Mathematica command in WolframAlpha and see what you get. You can also create a free WolframCloud account and work with Mathematica notebooks.

Answer (score 0):

Since you use $x$ in your question but have $z$ in the screenshots; do you want specifically plot the real and imaginary parts of $W(\operatorname{exp}(-z))$ for complex $z$?

If you are satisfied with the plot as a real function, you can simply ask WolframAlpha to "plot y*e^y = e^(-x)" (this just uses the definition of the lambert $W$ function to rewrite the equation).